# Retrieve original stage width and height after scale

Tags: actionscript-3, actionscript, size, stage

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the "ORIGINAL" stage height and width that was set during compile of an Air/Flash Application

I have set the Application to compile to 1920x1080;

I have stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;

and stage.nativeWindow.maximize();

But when I trace stage.stageWidth I get 1280 which is the resolution of the screen.

I was hoping to get the 1920.

I cannot use stage.width or stage.getBounds(stage) because this returns 6000. Due to items being masked off screen.

With the stage.stageWidth being the screen resolution, I was hoping I could use that and mathematically work out the original using stage.scaleX. but even with SHOW_ALL scaling the entire application, stage.scaleX returns 1.

I would love to hardcode 1920x1080 into the application, but this code is being used in multiple applications of various dimensions. And now I have become stumped.

Any help would be welcome.

EDIT: I know what "Show all" does, you do not need to tell me about it.

I also know what stage.width and stage.stageWidth do, but stage.stageWidth is returning what I believe is incorrect in this example and need an alternative.

Resize does not help either as I need it after the fact.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

when you are setting:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
```

the `Event.RESIZE` is not beeing dispatched from the `stage`, because no RESIZE of the stage is happening.

`stage.width` - is the parameter which gives you the size of all the display objects placed on it ( imagine everything what is places on the stage as a one MC ).

`stage.stageWidth` - this parameter will give you back the default width only ( because no REIZE is happening, since you have `scaleMode=SHOWALL`, normally it does return the visible flash stage size.

If you want to get the size of a screen ( device rezolution ):

```
Capabilities.screenResolutionX
```

---

`SHOW_ALL` parameter for scaleMode says application to stretch to the flash display size.

If you want to change something for different sizes of the screen / flash display stage,
you need to use `NO_SCALE` property.

p.s. for width parameter same rules applies.

**UPDATE**

After some testing found a solution for it:

```
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; // reseting the scale to get actual width
ACTUAL_STAGE_WIDTH = stage.stageWidth; // this is where you getting the width you need
stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL; // setting back the scale.
```

Comment: You are incorrect, stage.stageWidth does NOT give back the correct result.

and NO, I do not wish to get the Screen Resolution.That is, as you have shown, is easy to get hold of.

I am unfortunately unable to downgrade your answer a "Down Vote". I know what all the properties do that you have shown, I am a little confused why you have chosen to list them here though.

Comment: please read it everything again. `stage.stageWidth` will be returning you the correct value only when you will be using `stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE;`

Comment: Because it is the only way you will get the parameters you need.

Comment: Edited the answer. Have found a solution for you.

Comment: Thats better than my solution.. I decided to store the values as a static var before calling setting the scalemode and maximizing when the app first starts.. Will this not cause the screen to try and redraw? or will I be able to get away with it since its all happening within the same frame cycle? Also, I've marked the answer and voted up..

Comment: The thing is that the changes happening in the same frame, so there will be no stage redrawing ( this is my theory ).

Answer (score 3):

@Jevgenij Dmitrijev solution was a bit of a hack. (No Offense)

The real answer for getting the published SWF Size is using

```
this.loaderInfo.width;
this.loaderInfo.height;
```

Found it on an older actionscript forum and it was something that i myself forgot.

you can look up loader info on ASdoc's and they'll give you an in-depth explanation.

Comment: Thank you for this. There is a small issue with this solution`Error #2099: The loading object is not sufficiently loaded to provide this information.`. Now if I put a timer in and do this, it works, but I don't feel much like using a hack to have this solution to work. What I did in the end was just use a class with static variables to hold the height and width which is set on construction. Not exactly cleaver, but some times Dumb approaches seem the most confident.

Comment: I just remembered another way to use this approach. `loaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, _onComplete_info);` `private function _onComplete(__e:Event):void { trace(loaderInfo.width, loaderInfo.height); }`

Comment: you can't use the loaderInfo property straight off the bat, you have to make sure the SWF has completed loading. you should hold off initializing your app until it has completed loading. everything references the apllication's loader info so you can use it on any level except for the `stage.loaderInfo` the stage's loader info never loads.

Comment: ..... Yes.. hence why I posted the onComplete function.. I dont understand the reason you posted just now?